# When the Next js app refreshing, useEffect not dispatching redux saga action and updating the state

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, next.js, redux-saga

My question is, when the next js app refreshing/reloading, redux store state not updating. I have the below code inside the component

```
const Landing = () => {
   const freeADS = useSelector((state) => state.ads.freeAds); //this states are working fine without page refresh
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchFreeAds());
    }, [])

  return(
    {freeADS.map((data, i) => {
       //some codings.........
    })}
  )
}
export default Landing;
```

redux action call

```
export const fetchFreeAds = () => {
    return {
        type: ActionTypes.FETCH_FREE_ADS
    }
}
```

after the rootsaga / watch saga get the request, I call the handler like below

```
export function* handleFreeAds() {
    
    const { response, error } = yield call(fetchFreeAds);

    if (response)
    {
        yield put({type:"SET_FREE_ADS", payload: response.data[0]});
    }
    else{
        
    }
}
```

actual api call goes here

```
export function fetchFreeAds() {
    return axios.get('http://xxxxxxxxxx')
        .then(response => ({ response }))
        .catch(error => ({ error }))
}
```

I'm getting this error at the moment. pls give some support. thanks

[image]

Comment: The associated data is not populated until the API returns. You could give the state slice an initial state. E.g. `state = { ads: { freeAds: [] } }`

Comment: @slideshowp2 this is how manage the state `export interface State{freeAds: null}` `export const adReducers = (state = {}, {type, payload}) => { ...... } `

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @slideshowp2

Problem solved by doing this miner modification. Added **freeAds:[ ]** backet to the initial state.

```
export interface State{
   freeAds: null
}
export const adReducers = (state = {freeAds:[]}, {type, payload}) => {
 switch(type)
 case ActionTypes.SET_FREE_ADS:
        return { 
           ...state,
           freeAds: payload
        };
 }
```